# gawk "not equal to", field separator

Tags: awk

```
gawk -F ";" '!($2 == "-") {print $0}' file.csv > out.file
```

This is my file:

```
MYH1;Myosin-1;MYH1_HUMAN
CALML6;Calmodulin-like;protein
UNQ6494;-;-
```

This is the output I want:

```
MYH1;Myosin-1;MYH1_HUMAN
CALML6;Calmodulin-like;protein
```

I  thought that I understood this, but I get this output (same as input):

```
MYH1;Myosin-1;MYH1_HUMAN
CALML6;Calmodulin-like;protein
UNQ6494;-;-
```

Comment: Your command seems to work as expected for me. gawk 3.1.7, tested in bash, sh, and csh.

Comment: Yes, I thought it would... But it doesn't ... :S

Comment: Which gawk version are you using? Which shell?

Comment: Terminal 2.4 (Osx Maverick). GAWK 4.0.2.

Comment: `dos2unix file.csv` if your file was sourced from a PC? (as you mention OSX, doesn't seem likely). Good luck.

Comment: You my man, helped me solve it! I just saved the .csv as .txt. :P WORKS!

Comment: You got the answer, but FYI your whole script can be written as just `gawk -F ';' '$2 != "-"' file.csv`

Comment: why not `$2!~"-"`? I think that `$2` can't equal (or inequal) to `"-"`

Comment: Because $2!~"-" is evaluated to 1 if $2 matches (anywhere) to the regex "-", 0 otherwise. That meaning gawk -F ";" '$2!~"-"' file.csv will not show any line because "Myosin-1" and "Calmodulin-like" match to /-/ (cause they have a dash inside).